# No provider for Router?

Tags: angular, routes

Im getting this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline
> template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Router!

This is my app component:

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/components/login.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<login></login>',

})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

I tried this in my app module:

```ts
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    LoginModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, RouterModule]
```

But then i get this error:

> Error: Error: No Directive annotation found on RouterModule

I found some examples but they use router-deprecated, and i dont have that folder. Do i need that or what? Any suggstion?

UPDATE:

This is my app.module:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//import 'rxjs/Rx';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    LoginModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component:

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/components/login.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<login></login>',

})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

And then i have login.component:

```ts
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { Login } from '../model/login'
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login-form',

})
export class LoginComponent {
  // Constructor with injected service
      constructor(
          private loginService: LoginService,
          private router: Router
          ){}

      submitLogin(values){

          // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
             let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
             loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
             loginOperation.subscribe(
                function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
                function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
                function() {
                   console.log("the subscription is completed");
                     this.router.navigate(['/About']);

                 }
            );

           }
}
```

Maybe problem is in this line:

```ts
 this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

This is my login.module:

```ts
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    RouterModule  


  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],

  providers: [
      LoginService
  ],

  exports:[
    LoginComponent
  ]

})
export class LoginModule {
}
```

Comment: Why you are bootstraping `RouteModule` ? remove it from `bootstrap: [AppComponent, RouterModule]` it should be `bootstrap: [AppComponent]`

Comment: ok.. but again im getting  error  that there is no provider for router

Comment: update question and post your complete app module code

Comment: Where are your routes?

Comment: Your module is okie please add your app component code seems like error is from there not your module

Comment: the `RouterModule` needs to be initialized with routes like `imports: [RouterModule.forRoute(myRoutes)]`

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html says how you should initalize router module.. you need to provide the routes

Comment: Please add your `LoginComponent` to `NgModule` declerations

Comment: @BabarBilal i have login.module where i have LoginComponent in declaratiosn.

Comment: Have you added the router module with routes ?

Comment: I added them now and now i get this error: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'

Comment: Okie now just replace your `<login></login>` with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` thats it

Comment: tnx ... u can post r answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please use this module

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    { path: "", component: LoginComponent}
  ]
)
```

now just replace your `<login></login>` with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` thats it

Answer (score 41):

I have also received this error when developing automatic tests for components. In this context the following import should be done:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";

const testBedConfiguration = {
  imports: [SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
  ],
```

Comment: solution worked when faced with the error in setting up the boilerplate code in unit testing. +1

Answer (score 23):

Babar Bilal's answer likely worked perfectly for earlier Angular 2 alpha/beta releases.  However, anyone solving this problem with Angular release v4+ may want to try the following change to his answer instead (wrapping the single route in the required array):

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: "", component: LoginComponent}])
```

Comment: What is the difference? Bilal's answer and yours seem identical to me.

Comment: They are identical now as one of the answers has been edited.

Answer (score 6):

> Nothing works from this tread. "forRoot" doesn't help.

Sorry. Sorted this out.
I've managed to make it work by setting correct "routes" for this "forRoot" router setup routine

```js
    import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';    
    import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
    
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {path: 'UI/part1/Details', component: DetailsComponent}
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DetailsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [DetailsService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

Also may be helpful (spent some time to realize this)
**Optional** route part:

```js
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
       {path: 'UI/part1/Details', component: DetailsComponent},
       {path: ':project/UI/part1/Details', component: DetailsComponent}
    ];
```

Second rule allows to open URLs like
`hostname/test/UI/part1/Details?id=666`
and
`hostname/UI/part1/Details?id=666`

Been working as a frontend developer since 2012 but never stuck in a such over-complicated thing as angular2 (I have 3 years experience with enterprise level ExtJS)

Answer (score 1):

I had the error of

> No provider for Router

It happens when you try to navigate in `any service.ts`

`this.router.navigate(['/home']);` like codes in services cause that error.

You should handle navigating in your components. for example: at `login.component`

```
login().subscribe(
        (res) => this.router.navigate(['/home']),
        (error: any) => this.handleError(error));
```

Annoying errors happens when we are newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

If you created a separate module (eg. `AppRoutingModule`) to contain your routing commands you can get this same error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
```

You may have forgotten to import it to the main `AppModule` as shown here:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, Page1Component, Page2Component ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a `routerLink="."` attribute at one of my HTML tags which caused that error

Answer (score -3):

Please do the import like below:

**import { Router } from '@angular/Router';**

The mistake that was being done was -> import { Router } from '@angular/router';