# No provider for router Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router, angular-providers

I'm developping an angular application ,I'm not using Routes anywhere in my project but I get this error in my web dev tool :

```
ERROR Error: No provider for Router!
Trace de la pile :
injectionError@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1369:90
noProviderError@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1407:12
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._throwOrNull@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:2849:19
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:2888:20
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:2820:20
...
...
resolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9688:17
_createClass@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9729:29
_createProviderInstance$1@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9703:26
resolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9688:17
_createClass@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9729:29
_createProviderInstance$1@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9703:26
resolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:9688:17
NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:10762:16
resolveDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:11250:12
createClass@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:11114:85
createDirectiveInstance@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:10951:37
createViewNodes@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12392:53
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12822:13
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12731:13
createViewNodes@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12420:5
createRootView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12282:5
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:13667:39
debugCreateRootView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12971:12
ComponentFactory_.prototype.create@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:10061:37
ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.prototype.create@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3533:16
ApplicationRef_.prototype.bootstrap@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4968:40
PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4746:74
PlatformRef_.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4746:13
PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</</<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4708:21
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvoke@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4090:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:17
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:858:52
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4081:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25
  AppComponent.ngfactory.js:9:80
```

In the terminal , the project is compiling correcty.

ng -v gives this.

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 6.3.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
... tsc-wrapped

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Yesterday it was working , the main difference is that I have added some abstract classes, services, and Http requests

Comment: you might be using something that requires routing itself (e.g. some other module)

Comment: type ng -v and share the details on the console

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829796/no-provider-for-router)

Comment: I have updated my post. @RameshRajendran it's not a duplicate, because I'm not using Router actually in my project.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829796/no-provider-for-router