# Angular 6:redirect after login

Tags: angular

Hi all this is my code for login in my site.
My code work, but  i have problem with redirect to another html page.
I have this error message

> NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!

Import items:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {requestService} from '../request.service';
import {functionComponent} from '../function.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {Router, Routes} from '@angular/router';
```

Decorator

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
```

My action code:

```
  export class LoginComponent {

        email: string;
        password: string;
        getStructure: object;
        getData: object;


        constructor(
            private request: requestService,
            private callFunction: functionComponent,
            private cookie: CookieService,
            public router: Router

        ) {}


        login() {

            this.getStructure = this.callFunction.getBasicLogin(this);
            this.request.getRequest(this.getStructure).subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    // this.getData = data.Authentication.AccessToken;
                    console.log(data.Authentication.AccessToken)
                    if (data.Authentication.AccessToken) {
                        console.log('Hello')
                        this.cookie.set('AccessToken', data.Authentication.AccessToken);
                        console.log(this.cookie.get('AccessToken'));
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Exit')
                    }
                }
            );
        }

    }

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
//import {Router} from'@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import {requestService} from './request.service';
import {functionComponent} from './function.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
```

section NgModel

@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductComponent,
        LoginComponent,
         // functionComponent

```
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      CommonModule,
      HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [requestService, functionComponent, CookieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: share your app.module?

Comment: Did you import the routerModule in your app.module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829796/no-provider-for-router)

Comment: so, refer to my answer, you have no routerModule imported to your module..

Comment: Sory no understand!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://alligator.io/angular/introduction-routing-angular/)

Comment: I want redirect from component to html, my code is login after login redirect to....

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that you simply do not have Router imported to your main module:

```
@import {RouterModule} '@angular/router';
...
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
]
```

Where AppRoutes are your defined routes (paths and so on)

Comment: In my app.module, and add this  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login') in my login.component, but no works I want navigate to login.html how?

Comment: @stencyGergiev use router.navigate() to navigate inside the component

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/login']) this is no work,url in my browser is http://localhost:4200/login, but my html page no change!

Comment: where is my problem? when open my page is localhost:420, i write username i password in my login form and click after click localhost:4200/login but my page is no change?