# Getting the current URL gives the static injector error for Router

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am building an Angular and Ionic application where I need the URL of my current page, the url that is showing in the address bar of the browser. To do so, I am using router.url, But I am getting an error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[Router]:
>   StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Router! Error: StaticInjectorError[Router]:    StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
>       at *NullInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1277:19)
>       at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1565:24)
>       at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1507:16)
>       at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1378:20)
>       at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1565:24)
>       at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1507:16)
>       at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1378:20)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10939:25)
>       at NgModuleRef*.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12160:16)
>       at resolveDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12656:45)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
>       at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
>       at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:50002:16)
>       at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:49995:14)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:50042:59
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4983:33)
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
>       at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242

Component code is:

```
import {Component, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform, ViewController, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ScreenOrientation} from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { ApiProvider } from './../../providers/api/api';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-play',

    templateUrl: 'play.html',
    providers: [ScreenOrientation]
})

export class PlayPage {

    constructor(platform: Platform,private router: Router, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController, private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation, public toastCtrl: ToastController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public apiProvider: ApiProvider) {


this.location=this.router.url;
        console.log("LOCATION"+this.location);
    }
}
```

My module.ts is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { TabPage } from '../pages/tab/tab';
import {VgCoreModule} from 'videogular2/core';
import {VgControlsModule} from 'videogular2/controls';
import {VgOverlayPlayModule} from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import {VgBufferingModule} from 'videogular2/buffering';
import { ApiProvider } from '../providers/api/api';
//import { Databaseservice } from '../providers/api/Databaseservice';
import {GetstartedPage} from '../pages/getstarted/getstarted'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {LoginPage} from '../pages/login/login';
import {LoginPageModule} from '../pages/login/login.module'
import {SongsPage} from '../pages/songs/songs'
import {SongsPageModule} from '../pages/songs/songs.module'
import {VideosPage} from '../pages/videos/videos'
import {VideosPageModule} from '../pages/videos/videos.module'
import {EmbedvideoPage} from '../pages/embedvideo/embedvideo'
import {EmbedvideoPageModule} from '../pages/embedvideo/embedvideo.module'
import {PlayPage} from '../pages/play/play'
import {PlayPageModule} from '../pages/play/play.module'
import {EventsPage} from '../pages/events/events'
import {EventsPageModule} from '../pages/events/events.module'
import {ProfilePage} from '../pages/profile/profile'
import {ProfilePageModule} from '../pages/profile/profile.module'
import {SettingsPage} from '../pages/settings/settings'
import {SettingsPageModule} from '../pages/settings/settings.module'
import {AudioplayertwoPage} from '../pages/audioplayertwo/audioplayertwo'
import {AudioplayertwoPageModule} from '../pages/audioplayertwo/audioplayertwo.module'
import {ViewAllPage} from '../pages/view-all/view-all'
import {ViewAllPageModule} from '../pages/view-all/view-all.module'


import {PricePage} from '../pages/price/price'
import {PricePageModule} from '../pages/price/price.module'
import { GetstartedPageModule } from '../pages/getstarted/getstarted.module';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/messaging'; // only import firebase messaging or as needed;
import { firebaseConfig } from '../environment';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule,Router } from '@angular/router';



firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var database = firebase.database();
//.............
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        TabPage,
        // SingleMediaPlayer
    ],


    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
            links: [
                  { component: LoginPage, name: 'LoginPage', segment: 'login' },
                { component: SongsPage, name: 'SongsPage', segment: 'songs' },
                { component: VideosPage, name: 'VideosPage', segment: 'm/videos' },
                { component: EventsPage, name: 'EventsPage', segment: 'm/events' },
                { component: PlayPage, name: 'PlayPage', segment: 'm/watch/:name' },
                { component: EmbedvideoPage, name: 'EmbedvideoPage', segment: 'embed' },
                { component: ProfilePage, name: 'ProfilePage', segment: 'profile' },
                { component: SettingsPage, name: 'SettingsPage', segment: 'settings' },
                { component: PricePage, name: 'PricePage', segment: 'price' },
                { component: AudioplayertwoPage, name: 'AudioplayertwoPage', segment: 'Audioplayer' },
                { component: TabPage, name: 'TabPage', segment: 'tab' } ,
                 { component: ViewAllPage, name:'ViewAllPage',segment:'m/viewAll/:name'}
            ]
        }),
        SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
        VgCoreModule,
        VgControlsModule, PlayPageModule, ProfilePageModule, SettingsPageModule, PricePageModule, AudioplayertwoPageModule,
        VgOverlayPlayModule, GetstartedPageModule, LoginPageModule, SongsPageModule, VideosPageModule, EventsPageModule, EmbedvideoPageModule,
        VgBufferingModule, VideosPageModule, HttpClientModule, ViewAllPageModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), IonicStorageModule.forRoot(), AngularFireDatabaseModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
       VideosPage, GetstartedPage
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }, ApiProvider
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I know something I have to add in my module.ts. But I am not figuring out it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829796/no-provider-for-router)

Answer (score 2):

You have to import `RouterModule` into your own module.

**EDIT** also put an access modifier in your first constructor parameter :

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, ...)
```

Or put it last in your parameters.

Comment: I have imported the `RouterModule` also, but the same issue is there.

Comment: Already there in the constructor as: `private router: Router`. I put it as the last param also.

Comment: That's not what I wrote. I told you to put it on `Platform`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in your module imports?

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    { path: "", component: PlayPage}
  ]
)
```

Comment: Instead of vulturing points by posting a duplicate answer of a similar question, consider markinf this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/router says:

> A routed Angular application has one singleton instance of the Router service.

...

> A router has no routes until you configure it. The following example creates four route definitions, configures the router via the RouterModule.forRoot method, and adds the result to the AppModule's imports array.

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So in order to use Router instance, you need to create it first in your root module using RouterModule.forRoot method. You can follow the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/router) - it's quite simple.

Comment: I updated my question with module.ts file. I am using IonicModule for the deep linking of URL's.

Answer (score -1):

Add `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'`; in app.module.ts for Http

Or

Add `import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';` in app.module.ts for httpclient

Comment: The issue is with the router, not the http client.