# StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RegisterStoreComponent -> Router]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Router! Angular 5.2 / Karma-jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

**How to resolve this error?**

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the Router isn't being injected into your test...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829796/no-provider-for-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following to the imports on your app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: "", component: LoginComponent}
      ]
    )
```