# StaticInjectorError and NullInjectorError on using router in angular

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { DslistingsComponent } from './dslistings/dslistings.component';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/Router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    DslistingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule, 
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatListModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{path:"", component: DslistingsComponent}])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as customUrl from '../CustomUrlSerializer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})


export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Why am I getting an error even when I have imported RouterModule in app.module file and then declared a private router in navbar.component.ts file ?
[image]

The html already has , I tried removing the private router: Router from the component.ts file and the page loads with no error its just when i try adding the router in the constructor I get

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NavbarComponent -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NavbarComponent -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NavbarComponent -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NavbarComponent -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
```

Comment: where is your ```<router-outlet></router-outlet>```

Comment: in app.component.html

Comment: import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/Router';
to import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router'; has removed the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829796/no-provider-for-router)